# I have trouble with my login form using flask

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

When I execute my login form I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

I tried different thing but didn't find the solution Please help

```py
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    error=None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Login1=request.form['exampleUsername']
        session['login']=Login1
        Password=request.form['exampleInputPassword1']
        req = db.execute('''select COUNT(*) from db.Users where Login = ((CONVERT(binary, %s)) and Password = %s ''', 
                (Login1, Password))
        db.commit()
        if req!=0 :
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            error = 'invalid credential.Please try again or register'
            return render_template("index.html",error=error)
    else:           
        return render_template("index.html",error=error)
```

Comment: Can u post on which line u r getting error?

Comment: The error isn't in the code you posted.

Comment: File "c:\users\pregnon wilfried\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1067, in _execute_clauseelement
    keys = list(distilled_params[0].keys())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2019 15:54:41] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: `distilled_params[0]` isn't a dictionary, here you can find how to use the method keys() https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_keys.asp